# ¿Cómo configurar abrir proyectos correctamente en IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Probablemente sea una consulta super básica pero me suele pasar que cada vez que quiero abrir un proyecto externo (que yo no lo haya creado desde mi IntelliJ) y comenzar a editarlo, IntelliJ me lee el proyecto como File por lo que tampoco me sale la opción de correr el código, los errores que tiene, no puedo crear Clases ni nada de eso.

Alguien sabe como puedo gestionar eso?
Esto solo me pasa cuando quiero editar algún proyecto externo.

Adjunto imagen de ejemplo, si se fijan en los que deberían ser "Clases" en realidad solo aparecen como File.

Gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba cerrar Intellij, eliminar la carpeta `.idea` desde el explorer y volver a abrir Intellij

Comment: Dependiendo de la versión de intellij puedes tener la opción de "importar" está será siempre la más favorable ya que en ocasiones si se usa open sucede tu caso, al elegir importar proyecto se puede seleccionar el lenguaje, gestor de dependencias, entre otras configuraciones. ¡Espero que te sirva!